# Bootstrap 4 make navigation vertical on xs screen width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How to create this top navigation bar responsive using Bootstrap 4. By responsive I meant, I want to make this navigation bar collapse in small screens so it's neat.

I tried adding 'xs' for navigation, but it didn't work (it didn't collapse) .

Does bootstrap 4 support this feature? Or do we have to make custom styles to achieve this? Any input would be appreciated!

```css
/*
 * Masthead for nav
 */

.blog-masthead {
  background-color: #0275D8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
          box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

/* Nav links */
.blog-nav-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
}
.blog-nav-item:hover,
.blog-nav-item:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Active state gets a caret at the bottom */
.blog-nav .active {
  color: #fff;
}
.blog-nav .active:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: " ";
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}

* {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

* {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
          border-radius: 0 !important;
}

/*
 * Blog name and description
 */




/*
 * Footer
 */

.blog-footer {
  padding: 40px 0;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.blog-footer p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">

  
  <title>Bootstrap 4 Template</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Navigation Bar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sticky Footer.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style type="text/css">
    
    html,
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="blog-masthead col-xs-12">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="blog-nav">
                <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">New features</a>
                <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">Press</a>
                <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">New hires</a>
                <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">About</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: By "collapse", do you mean so it's hidden and toggleable by a button, or do you mean stacks vertically instead of horizontal? Also, there is no `xs` in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear enough. Yes I meant stacks vertically.

Comment: col-xs is not used in bootstrap 4, yout html is not complete and could not work, you need of navbar attribute after the navbar-toggler and after the div navbar-collapse...and if you want to create your own you must use @media on css....look here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [flexbox utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) which are responsive.

- Make the nav display:flex using `d-flex`
- Use `flex-sm-row` to make it horizontal on sm and up
- Use `flex-column` to make it vertical on xs

https://www.codeply.com/go/wNPuPmnAvw

```
 <div class="blog-masthead">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="blog-nav d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row">
            <a class="blog-nav-item active mr-2" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="blog-nav-item mr-2" href="#">New features</a>
            <a class="blog-nav-item mr-2" href="#">Press</a>
            <a class="blog-nav-item mr-2" href="#">New hires</a>
            <a class="blog-nav-item mr-2" href="#">About</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tks. Your solution almost worked. As I'm not using bootstrap navigation, is it possible for me to add a button to show the stack when screen is small ?

Comment: Why don't you use the [responsive Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)? Otherwise, you would use the [collapse component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) to toggle the display of the nav.

Comment: I tried to use it first, but the .caret didn't work with it.

Comment: I meant, I used original bootstrap responsive navbar first, but the caret point which shows the active page didn't work. That's why I created a seperate navigation.

Comment: By caret point, I meant the tiny triangle which indicated the current page under navbar.

Comment: sounds like it's custom. Bootstrap only changes color on active items